# Unable to drop table

Tags: apache-phoenix

I'm working on `HBase 0.98.12-hadoop2` and `phoenix-4.7.0`
I created table on phoenix to map with existing table on HBase.

After index testing, It failed to drop table with ERROR.

```
Error: ERROR 1010 (42M01): Not allowed to mutate table. tableName=my_table (state=42M01,code=1010)
```

To fix this, I tried to set `immutable_rows` to `true` but it didn't work.

```
0: jdbc:phoenix:localhost:2181:/hbase> alter table "my_table" set immutable_rows=false;
16/07/25 17:04:42 WARN query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl: Attempt to cache older version of my_table: current= 3, new=3
No rows affected (0.041 seconds)
0: jdbc:phoenix:localhost:2181:/hbase> drop table "my_table";
Error: ERROR 1010 (42M01): Not allowed to mutate table. tableName=my_table(state=42M01,code=1010)
```

How can I drop it? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I take a look into `SYSTEM.CATALOG` and I found something strange.

I don't know why and when it was inserted into there though,

after deleting it I could finally drop the table.

Comment: I am not sure what was "strange in SYSTEM.CATALOG" referred here, but if you have a view create using the table you can get "Not allowed to mutate table" error.

Answer (score 0):

There has to be some kind of reference to the table you are going to drop.

In my case there was a view that was referencing the table, so, first thing was to execute the `drop view` to delete that reference and after that the `drop table` command worked.